# Get sequence of types from HList in macro

Tags: scala, shapeless, scala-macros, hlist

**Context**: I'm trying to write a macro that is statically aware of an non-fixed number of types. I'm trying to pass these types as a single type parameter using an `HList`. It would be called as `m[ConcreteType1 :: ConcreteType2 :: ... :: HNil]()`. The macro then builds a match statement which requires some implicits to be found at compile time, a bit like how a json serialiser might demand implicit encoders. I've got a working implementation of the macro when used on a fixed number of type parameters, as follows:

```scala
def m[T1, T2](): Int = macro mImpl[T1, T2]

def mImpl[T1: c.WeakTypeTag, T2: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(): c.Expr[Int] = {
  import c.universe._
  val t = Seq(
    weakTypeOf[T1],
    weakTypeOf[T2]
  ).map(c => cq"a: $c => externalGenericCallRequiringImplicitsAndReturningInt(a)")
  val cases = q"input match { case ..$t }"
  c.Expr[Int](cases)
}
```

**Question**: If I have a `WeakTypeTag[T]` for some `T <: HList`, is there any way to turn that into a `Seq[Type]`?

```scala
def hlistToSeq[T <: HList](hlistType: WeakTypeTag[T]): Seq[Type] = ???
```

My instinct is to write a recursive match which turns each `T <: HList` into either `H :: T` or `HNil`, but I don't think that kind of matching exists in scala.

I'd like to hear of any other way to get a list of arbitrary size of types into a macro, bearing in mind that I would need a `Seq[Type]`, not `Expr[Seq[Type]]`, as I need to map over them in macro code.

A way of writing a similar 'macro' in Dotty would be interesting too - I'm hoping it'll be simpler there, but haven't fully investigated yet.

**Edit (clarification)**: The reason I'm using a macro is that I want a user of the library I'm writing to provide a collection of types (perhaps in the form of an `HList`), which the library can iterate over and expect implicits relating to. I say library, but it will be compiled together with the uses, in order for the macros to run; in any case it should be reusable with different collections of types. It's a bit confusing, but I think I've worked this bit out - I just need to be able to build macros that can operate on lists of types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you seem not to need macros. It seems type classes or `shapeless.Poly` can be enough.

```
def externalGenericCallRequiringImplicitsAndReturningInt[C](a: C)(implicit 
  mtc: MyTypeclass[C]): Int = mtc.anInt

trait MyTypeclass[C] {
  def anInt: Int
}
object MyTypeclass {
  implicit val mtc1: MyTypeclass[ConcreteType1] = new MyTypeclass[ConcreteType1] {
    override val anInt: Int = 1
  }

  implicit val mtc2: MyTypeclass[ConcreteType2] = new MyTypeclass[ConcreteType2] {
    override val anInt: Int = 2
  }

  //...
}

val a1: ConcreteType1 = null
val a2: ConcreteType2 = null
externalGenericCallRequiringImplicitsAndReturningInt(a1) //1
externalGenericCallRequiringImplicitsAndReturningInt(a2) //2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm writing a library that should take a collection of types as input (the `HList` discussed, perhaps), and can iterate through them, relying on `MyTypeclass[T]` for each, in various different contexts. I want the user of the library to be required to provide the appropriate implicit typeclasses, but only for the functionality they actually use. I think that to achieve this I need a macro that can generate calls as I have at compile time, based on the `HList`. Perhaps I've misunderstood, but I don't think I can do this without a macro.

Comment: I've added a clarification of why I need to use macros.

Comment: @gandaliter Sorry, still not clear why you need macros. Sounds like Shapeless can be enough (iterating over an HList is a typical use case, see `shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper`, `shapeless.ops.hlist.LiftAll`). Could you show example of iterating?

Comment: Looks like I underestimated shapeless! Just tried writing something now and it works exactly as I want it. Thanks a lot!